# Using Events with Shared subs?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a method that *should* be implemented as a `Shared` because it has no internal state:

```
Friend Class MMDates
    Friend Shared Sub Calculate(ByRef CP As DataPlug)
        MsgBox("dates was called with " & CP.Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I would like to allow that method to be called via a `RaiseEvent`, so I did:

```
Friend Class MMDates
    Friend Shared WithEvents DP As DataPlug
    Friend Shared Sub Calculate(ByRef CP As DataPlug) Handles DP.CalculateDates
        MsgBox("dates was called with " & CP.Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the caller, `DataPlug`, I added:

```
Public Event CalculateDates(ByRef CP As DataPlug)
Friend Sub Calculate()
    RaiseEvent CalculateDates(Me)
End Sub
```

All of this compiles fine, and `Raise` is called without error, but the event is never caught in `MMDates`. I implemented an alternative by adding this to `MMDates`:

```
Public Shared Sub StartListening()
    AddHandler DataPlug.CalculateDates, AddressOf Calculate
End Sub
```

...and then calling that in my app's startup routines. This is technically what I want - events do indeed end up calling shared methods. However, this link is created at runtime, even though it really is defined at compile-time.

So is this `Shared` event pattern possible in VB.net at compile time using a variation of `Handles` or some other syntax?

Comment: Do you ever set MMDates.DP to a DataPlug instance?  Is it the same instance where CalculateDates is raised?

Comment: `Friend Shared WithEvents DP As DataPlug` --> `... As NEW DataPlug`. Otherwise shared or not shared - works the same

Comment: As this is obviously related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41049863/1070452)  why not define an extension to do whatever to the collection (in the last Q it was a `List(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, String))`).  That way it would always be available and be added to each project the next time you work on them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the proper way to do this is with a `Partial` that you bake into the lower levels and then only fill out in the mix-in. So in my case I made a partial for `Calculate` in the base class, and the implementation in Calc, and presto!